# WSO2 Api Manager "try out" strange injecting unexpected headers values

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager

I'm finding some wird behaviours when testing deployed or published APIs through the built in Try Out feature of the WSO2 Api Manager publisher/development portal. The endpoint is a service exposed by WSO2 Micro Integrator.
When I invoke the API from Postman everything goes right. The API allows for GET method. Here is what I get from Postman:

**request header:**
[image]
**response header:**
[image]
When I run it from built in Try OUT function of WSO2AM publisher/development portals here's what I get (from Chrome Consolle):
**request header:**

```
GET /getusersubscriptions/1.0.0/?username=testcbald HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8243
Internal-Key: eyJraWQiOiJnYXRld2F5X2NlcnRpZmljYXRlX2FsaWFzIiwiYWxnIj....
Origin: https://localhost:9443
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: https://localhost:9443/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
accept: application/json
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="113", "Chromium";v="113", "Not-A.Brand";v="24"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
session_id: 6d0f4f8b-15e1-4ae1-8a2b-ef4426a55435
```

**response header:**

```
HTTP/1.1 403
Origin: https://localhost:9443
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, POST, PUT, GET
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
activityid: 681c1160-f9e7-4539-8fba-11c53ff2418c
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: 
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Origin
Expires: 0
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Date: Tue, 30 May 2023 16:16:50 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

By the way, in my ESB implementation of the microserver, I'm explicitly setting within the sequence, before calling the endpoint:

```
    <property name="Accept" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="application/json, text/plain, */*"/>
    <property name="Content-type" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
```

Finally, I add the screeshoot of the TRY OUT page:
[image]

It is for sure something related to the way the swagger.yaml is written. So I include its source too for completion:

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: getUserSubscriptions
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: /
security:
  - default: []
paths:
  /*:
    get:
      summary: >-
        pass d-flight username as an inline argument to the query. Session must
        be already active and the related session_id must be passed to the
        backend via header parameter 
      description: >-
        The username must mach with the user which created the session, unless
        the user itself has been granted with supervisory or authority role
      parameters:
        - name: username
          in: query
          required: true
          style: form
          explode: true
          schema:
            type: string
        - name: session_id
          in: header
          required: true
          style: simple
          explode: false
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: ok
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/positive'
      security:
        - default: []
      x-auth-type: Application & Application User
      x-throttling-tier: Unlimited
      x-wso2-application-security:
        security-types:
          - oauth2
        optional: false
components:
  schemas:
    positive:
      title: json object in case of positive response
      required:
        - resultCode
        - resultMsg
        - subscription
      type: object
      properties:
        resultCode:
          type: integer
        resultMsg:
          type: string
        subscription:
          required:
            - id
            - subscriptionEvent
            - subscriptionState
            - subscriptionType
            - timeBegin
            - timeEnd
            - username
          type: object
          properties:
            id:
              type: integer
            subscriptionType:
              type: string
            subscriptionState:
              type: string
            timeBegin:
              type: string
            timeEnd:
              type: string
            username:
              type: string
            subscriptionEvent:
              type: string
    unauthorized:
      title: json object in case of negative response from backend
      type: object
      properties:
        error:
          type: string
          description: error_alias
        error_description:
          type: string
          description: error description
    preconditions:
      title: json object in case of negative response from wso2 MI server
      type: object
      properties:
        result:
          type: string
          description: in such case should yield 'NOT OK'
        message:
          type: string
          description: a message explaining what went wrong and suggestiong fixes
  securitySchemes:
    default:
      type: oauth2
      flows:
        implicit:
          authorizationUrl: 'https://test.com'
          scopes: {}
x-wso2-auth-header: Authorization
x-wso2-cors:
  corsConfigurationEnabled: false
  accessControlAllowOrigins:
    - '*'
  accessControlAllowCredentials: false
  accessControlAllowHeaders:
    - authorization
    - Access-Control-Allow-Origin
    - Content-Type
    - SOAPAction
    - apikey
    - Internal-Key
    - Access-Control-Allow-Headers
    - session_id
  accessControlAllowMethods:
    - GET
    - PUT
    - POST
    - DELETE
    - PATCH
    - OPTIONS
x-wso2-production-endpoints:
  urls:
    - 'http://localhost:8290/dflightprod/epay/subscriptions'
  type: http
x-wso2-sandbox-endpoints:
  urls:
    - 'http://localhost:8290/dflightstaging/epay/subscriptions'
  type: http
x-wso2-basePath: /getusersubscriptions/1.0.0
x-wso2-transports:
  - http
  - https
x-wso2-response-cache:
  enabled: false
  cacheTimeoutInSeconds: 300
```

When invoking the API from Postman, everything goes nice and smoothly... Any guess? Thanks for helping :-)

**http_access...log**

```
- 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [31/May/2023:16:56:03.177 +0200] "OPTIONS /getusersubscriptions/1.0.0?username=testcbald HTTP/1.1" - - "https://localhost:9443/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
- 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1  - [31/May/2023:16:56:03.177 +0200] "- - " 200 - "-" "-"
- 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [31/May/2023:16:56:03.177 +0200] "GET /getusersubscriptions/1.0.0?username=testcbald HTTP/1.1" - - "https://localhost:9443/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
- 127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2023:16:56:03.187 +0200] "GET /dflightprod/epay/subscriptions?username=testcbald HTTP/1.1" - - "https://localhost:9443/" "Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO"
- 127.0.0.1  - [31/May/2023:16:56:03.187 +0200] "- - " 403 - "-" "-"
- 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1  - [31/May/2023:16:56:03.177 +0200] "- - " 403 - "-" "-"
```

**wso2carbon.log**

```
TID: [] [] [2023-05-31 16:56:03,177]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.SynapseHTTPRequestFactory} - HttpRequest from requestline
TID: [] [] [2023-05-31 16:56:03,177]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.SynapseHTTPRequestFactory} - HttpRequestFactory method: OPTIONS
TID: [] [] [2023-05-31 16:56:03,177]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.SynapseHTTPRequestFactory} - HttpRequestFactory uri: /getusersubscriptions/1.0.0?username=testcbald
TID: [] [] [2023-05-31 16:56:03,180]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.SynapseHTTPRequestFactory} - HttpRequest from requestline
TID: [] [] [2023-05-31 16:56:03,180]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.SynapseHTTPRequestFactory} - HttpRequestFactory method: GET
TID: [] [] [2023-05-31 16:56:03,180]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.SynapseHTTPRequestFactory} - HttpRequestFactory uri: /getusersubscriptions/1.0.0?username=testcbald
TID: [] [] [2023-05-31 16:56:03,186]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.ClientConnFactory} - ROUTE: localhost:8290
TID: [] [] [2023-05-31 16:56:03,413]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler} - connection pointing to http://localhost:8290/dflightprod/epay/subscriptions?username=testcbald with method GET
```

Comment: In your swagger definition have you specified a request body and it's content-type?

Comment: INDEED!!! Don't know how went there!       requestBody:
        description: ....
        content:
          payload_placeholder:
            schema:.....

Comment: after fixing, one API is working fine (as for with Postman). Another one still behave strangely:  only when run from TRY OUT I got no errors from WSO mi, but response from backend is 403 and Response headers
 cache-control: no-cache,no-store,max-age=0,must-revalidate 
 content-type: application/octet-stream... (I checked the swagger for this API, could no trace the word application/octed-stream :-(

Comment: Additionally, it yields Response body
Download file .... If I download the file and open it locally (with notepad) that's what I find inside: "OrderedMap {}"

Comment: You must be setting a Accept header or something. Can you compare the two requests and see what different?

Comment: I'll try to post oit as an answer, as using comments is not comfortable for long text with code fragments;-)

Comment: actually I'll edit the original question...

Comment: @ycr. It took a while to document the behaviour in a detailed manner. Hope you can get through and figure out what I'm still doing wrong. In the first case, was a very quick fix. Indeed a clear mistake in the yaml text. But for this second case seems something more hidden which I can't really spot :-( Thanks again for helping

Comment: Do you see any errors in the logs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253901/discussion-between-cristiano-and-ycr).